# Gtk# video player

Tags: c#, monodevelop, raspbian, gtk#, video-player

I just started using Gtk# with MonoDevelop on Raspbian, and i need to enable video playing in my application. I was thinking of making a widget (or use an existing one) to add to my window. Found some documentation on MPlayer but could not get it to work.

To rephrase my question, the task is just for my app to play a video, that could also be done by opening up a new window and playing it there.

Comment: Update: Managed to make MPlayer work, but it's just too slow since it does not use GPU acceleration for playing the video. I will look into Omxplayer and see if i can use it in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Omxplayer, since Mplayer was too slow, i did some research and found a simple solution that suited my needs. Calling the Omxplayer as a process before the initialisation of my app:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("omxplayer", "testVideo.mp4");
```

By default the video is played fullscreen, which was also what i was looking for.